# how can i use 3rd party jquery plugins in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, attributes, angular6

I'm trying to use the smooth_zoom plugin in angular app.
(http://vectorflower.com/preview/smooth_zoom/index.html).
its using custom html attributes but it seems this attributes not working in angular.
how can I use this library and other similar libraries in angular 6?
I've added jquery and smooth_zoom.min.js into "angular.json script path"
here is my code: homepage.html:

```
<div class="zoomHolder">
<img data-src="assets/images/1.png"   data-elem="pinchzoomer"/>
</div>
```

this is my homepage.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-home',
 templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
 styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})

export class HomePage implements OnInit{
 ngOnInit() {
    $(function($){
      $('#yourImageID').smoothZoom({
        width: 512,
        height: 384,
        pan_BUTTONS_SHOW: "NO",
        pan_LIMIT_BOUNDARY: "NO",
        button_SIZE: 24,
        button_ALIGN: "top right",    
        zoom_MAX: 300,
        border_TRANSPARENCY: 20,
        container: 'zoom_container'
     });
   });
 }
}
```

and this is part of angular.json:

```
"scripts": ["src/test/jquery.min.js",
"src/test/jquery.smoothZoom.min.js"]
```

when I run the app via angular serve,there is no error in consoleand  it seems the jquery and jquery.smoothZoom.min.js are loaded into scripts.js. the jquery is working but jquery.smoothZoom.min.js is not working. I think its because of the the data[src and data-elem attributes. this page works fine outside of angular but with angular  I've had no luck so far.
i'm new to angular and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your 3rd party `js` in assets folder any set path with assets in `script`

```
"scripts": [
   "src/test/jquery.min.js",
   "assets/yourpath/jquery.smoothZoom.min.js"
]
```

And then re-run `ng-serve` and check in network that js is load or not.

Comment: [ng] × ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Ali\ionic4\newapp2\newAppMenu\assets\js\jquery.min.js' .... when I correct the path to src/assets/js/jquery.min.js the error resolves and the jquery get loaded

Comment: using the path in angular.json loads the scripts but I don t know why its not working. actully if  I put console.log("somehing"); in the script I can see the message in console but the script dont communicate with the html attribute data-src and data-elem

Comment: Have you import `jquery` in your component ? By this : `import * as $ from 'jquery' `